# How to pass variable to endpoint nodejs

Tags: node.js, variables, get, endpoint

I have 2 endpoints.

1. It's:
   a) receive data from client
   b) + save this to file 
   c) + counts how many times data is saved.

```
    app.post('/api/v1', (req,res) => {

      var data = req.body;
      console.log(req.body)

      const storeData = (data, path) => {
        try {
          console.log("Uploading data to file...")
          fs.appendFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(data))
          counter = counter +1;
          console.log(counter);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
      }
    storeData(data,'./files/data.json');
```

2. It's:
   a) Send data do client

```
app.get('/api/counter', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({

  })
});
```

My question is :

"How can I modify second endpoint to get counter from first endpoint and send it to client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically asking for a simple state management module.

I would recommend using a global counter to store the count. Increment the counter in the first endpoint and then access the same in the second. Or else setup an external state management for the same - either storing the counter in a file system or a db (not recommended)

```
var counter;

function setCount(num=0){
    counter = num;
}

function inc(){
    counter++;
}

function getCount(){
    return counter;
}

module.exports = {
    inc: inc,
    setCount: setCount,
    getCount: getCount
};
```

In your file with the API endpoints

```
const arb = require('./path/name_of_your_arbitrary_file');

...
// Increment in 1st endpoint
arb.inc();

...
// Get Count in 2nd endpoint
var count = arb.getCount();
```

Comment: @PiotrŻak Just updated the answer above. You should be able to call it within your 2nd endpoint here.

Comment: var count = arb.getCount(); is not working for second endpoint ( 1st works)

Comment: It's error, when i change it like this: var:count = arb.getCount(),
But in front i get empty object.

Comment: And when i console.log it 2nd - it's always 0

Comment: Added a repl. Check this [link](https://repl.it/repls/JauntyDarlingGraph) Run the repl and then open the endpoints in the browser. I think it works fine.

Comment: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: when I apply it to my client-server solution

Comment: Are you using the `arb.setCount()` to initialize the counter?
Or else you can eliminate the `setCount` function altogether and implement the following `counter = counter == null ? 1 : counter+1;` in `inc()`. Check the repl for the updated code.

Comment: when i call arb.inc(), how can I check counter in console.log ?
console.log(arb.counter) gives undefined

Comment: You would use `arb.getCount()` at any point to check the state of the counter.

Comment: Ok i tested it, It works on 1st endpoints - increment well

But how can i define it in 2st to return 'counter' to response to get from frontend

Comment: Ok, i saw in my React App console (1) !